# Find the probability that the average of X and Z is greater than Y. Where X, Z, and Y are normal RVs.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Here is the exact statement:

Suppose X,Y , and Z are independent random variables. X is a normal random variable with mean 5 and variance 16, Y is a normal random variable with mean 7 and variance 25, and Z is a normal random variable with mean 10 and variance 9.

Then, Find the probability that the average of X and Z is greater than Y

*End problem statement*

For this problem, I think I want to figure out the $P\{E[X] + E[Z] > E[Y]\}$ as expected values are averages. However, I am unsure of where to go from here. Should I first find the probability density function for X + Z and Y using the normal pdf and sums of normal random variables? A small hint would be appreciated. This is the follow up question from a part before in which I found the value of $k$ such that $P\{X + Y + Z \le k\}$. However, I feel that this part is unrelated. Is that correct?

I'm sorry for the lack of information, but the past hour of scouring my book and notes for information where to start has not been founded with luck. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer cannot be found unless you specify what the _joint_ distribution of $X,Y,Z$ is. Read the problem assigned to you carefully. Does it say that $X,Y,Z$ are _independent?_ Or does it say that $X,Y,Z$ are _jointly normal_ with some covariance matrix? If so, **edit the problem statement above** to include this information. Don't make folks wade through a long series of comments to discover this important fact.  Also, $E[X], E[Y]$ etc are _not_ random variables, just ordinary numbers, and it makes no sense to ask for $P\{E[X]+E[Z]>E[Y]\}$

Comment: What you are likely to have been asked to find is $\displaystyle P\left\{\frac{X+Z}{2} > Y\right\}$, and not $P\{E[X] + E[Z] > E[Y]\}$ as you claim.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these are independent. The problem statement is the title of the question. So the average of the sum is just the means divided by 2 and then I can use pdfs to find this probability?

Comment: If the problem statement is _exactly_ the title of the question, then **where** does it say that $X,Y,Z$ are independent?

Comment: Here is the exact statement:

Suppose $X, Y$ , and $Z$ are independent random variables. $X$ is a normal random variable
with mean 5 and variance 16, $Y$ is a normal random variable with mean 7 and variance 25,
and $Z$ is a normal random variable with mean 10 and variance 9.


Then, Find the probability that the average of X and Z is greater than Y.

Comment: To answer the question you insist on asking, you are given that $E[X]=5$, $E[Y]=7$ and $E[Z]=10$. Thus, it is _always_ true that $$E[X]+E[Z] = 5+10 = 15 > 7 = E[Y]$$ and so the probability that _you_ want to find, viz. $P\{E[X] + E[Z] > E[Y]\}$ is necessarily $1$. Notice that the variances and the independence that I was fussing about are all irrelevant for the purposes of this calculation. On the other hand, since the word "average" does not apply to $Y$ in your statement, you are asked to find $P\{E[X] + E[Z] > Y\} = P\{15 > Y\}$ which you should be able to find easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Hint:**
>   $$
>   \Pr \! \left( \frac{X + Z}{2} > Y \right)
> = \Pr(X + Z - 2 Y > 0).
> $$

Any linear combination of normal random variables that are *jointly normally distributed* is also a normal random variable (so its probability density function is completely described by its mean and variance).

Comment: "Any linear combination of normal random variables is normally distributed" is false unless the random variables are _jointly_ normal (which, fortunately, they happen to be in this instance because they are independent, a fact that has at last been wrung from the OP).